# Cannot continue incremental backups after restoring from Time Machine

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, backup, restore, time-machine

I recently restored a machine (running Snow Leopard) of mine from Time Machine and the restore went well. After restoring, I attempted to back up to Time Machine again (on the same external hard drive I have always used) and I noticed that Time Machine was deleting old backups for that computer. After some waiting, it gives me a message saying that there is not enough space on the disk to perform a new backup (it needs 237GB free but there is only ~200GB free). But I want the backups to be added to the previous ones like they have always been in the past.

What should I do? If there is no chance of me getting Time Machine to do what I want it to do, is there software out there that lets me manipulate my TM backups easily? It would really suck to lose all those previous backups just because I had to restore...

Answer (score 0):

In system preferences under the Sharing pane check to see if the computer name is the same as the folder in the Backups.backupsdb folder in the time machine volume.

Comment: Just checked it. It is the same, but it still insists on doing a completely new backup.